# How to access the content from DataBase, "not using the primary key"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**ASP NET CORE - Using EF Core**

Table:

1. UserBooksId  - Primary Key
2. UserId - the userId from another table
3. BookId - the bookId from another table
4. BookToBuy - where i keep my content
5. NrBooksOrdered - the number of the books ordered

*So I don't know how to acces the content of this table using the UserId - > BookToBuy and NrBooksOrdered or even all the Primary Keys that have this userId.*

Primary Key being unique, doesn't help me to much, because in the database, the UserId can be in the database multiple times, as well the bookid.

Example:

1. UserBookId:0 | UserId:1 | BookId:2 | BookToBuy:Wizzard | NrBooksOrdered:2
2. UserBookId:1 | UserId:1 | BookId:2 | BookToBuy:Wizzard | NrBooksOrdered:6
3. UserBookId:2 | UserId:1 | BookId:3 | BookToBuy:LongRoad | NrBooksOrdered:1

As you can see the UserId doesn't change.

Thank you.

Comment: `TableName.Where(z=> conditionhere)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use basic [linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) queries here

```cs
/* b is a reference here to every book, so you can filter it by the bool-expression */
var booksQuery = dbcontext.BooksTable.Where(b => b.UserId == 1 && b.BookId == 2);

/* books will be type of IQueryable so it isnt retrieved from the database */
/* yet. To do so, you can use `.ToList()` or `.AsEnumerable()` (wich is    */
/* faster in use-cases, where you need to iterate the result once)         */
var booksFromDb = booksQuery.AsEnumerable();
```

For a detailed description, on how to query data with EF-Core you can always refer back to: [MS-Docs Querying Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/)

Comment: Thank you. Now It works. I will do my research, on linq and queries

Comment: One thing to add, I didn't think that with the UserId I can get the object of the table, with each of the primary key.  I always thought you can do that only with the primary key.

Comment: Most Linq queries until `AsEnumerable()` or `ToString()` will be translated to SQL and executed on the SQL Server for better performance.

Comment: @SilviuM You're welcome. Also keep in mind, if you're iterating the result ore then once, replace the `AsEnumerable()` with `ToString()`